# following system of inequalities

Tags: inequality, graphing-functions

Graph the following system of inequalities.

$$x+2y\leq 12$$
$$2x+y\leq 12$$

$$x\geq 0 ,   y \geq 0$$

[image]

I just need to know how Can  show the augmented matrix that describes the situation

Comment: Surely you mean the simplex tableau associated with this system of inequalities.

Comment: yes that I mean

Comment: Okay, I assume you are fine graphing it. Also for the simplex tableau, you will need the objective function.

Comment: yes  please     anybody help